# Change span to font ckeditor color button

Tags: ckeditor

Ckeditor add `<span></span>` tag to element after change color from editor

I need to change tag to `<font></font>`

I review the code in ckeditor.js and don't found anything about color

Comment: You can traverse the DOM and remove the `<span>` and add the right tag

Answer (score 0):

To switch span to font add those two lines on ckeditor config.js file.

```
  config.colorButton_backStyle.element = 'font';
  config.colorButton_foreStyle.element = 'font';
```

You can now what you can do more at it's [manual](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-colorButton_backStyle).

This is my ckeditor config.js, with those two lines:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.toolbarGroups = [
    {name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools']},
    {name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo']},
    {name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker']},
    {name: 'forms'},
    {name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup']},
    {name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'bidi']},
    {name: 'align'},
    '/',
    {name: 'links'},
    {name: 'insert'},
    {name: 'styles'},
    {name: 'colors'},
    {name: 'tools'},
    {name: 'others'}
  ];

  config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
  config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
  config.extraPlugins = 'font,justify,keyword,colorbutton,dropoff,colordialog';
  config.skin = 'heisenberg';
  config.language = 'pt-br';
  config.disallowedContent = "img,script,style";
  config.colorButton_enableMore = true;

  // it change span tag to font tag, mental note, plugin must already been loaded.
  config.colorButton_backStyle.element = 'font';
  config.colorButton_foreStyle.element = 'font';
};
```